# Input text file of strings and integers

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer

I have a data file (ordered_data.txt) composed of 8 columns of integers and the last column is a string. It is 2912 rows long. I am inputting the data like so:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(('ordered_data.txt'), invalid_raise = False)
```

This obviously converts the last column to all 'nan'. This has been fine for running my code because I only need the integers to do that. The output of my code is essentially taking the original text file and splitting it into two different files based on certain parameters. The problem is that now the two new files I've created all have 'nan' as the 9th column, when I need the original strings to still be there.

I had tried inputting the data like this:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(('ordered_data.csv'), invalid_raise = False, delimiter = ',', 
                     dtype = [('Glong', float), ('Glat', float), ('Rgal', float), 
                              ('Radius', float), ('Velocity', float),
                              ('Second Velocity', (str,10)),
                              ('Distance', float), ('Distance_Error', float), 
                              ('Name', (str,16))])
```

This produced the following output:

> (0.279081, -0.481935, 0.392097, 60.0, 20.0, '18.5;12.6', 0.0, 0.0, 'G000.284-00.478')

The 6th column is technically supposed to be a string as well, but that can be ignored for now, it's not as important. It will be the exact same problem as the 9th column I think.

Now, instead of having 9 columns of values, where the last is a string, I now have the whole row grouped into one column.

I have tried reorganizing the data using vstack, hstack, and concatenating lists but I believe there should be a simple solution for this and I'm making it more difficult than it needs to be. I need a new pair of eyes to tell me what my mistake is because I have become too involved in it. If someone could tell me how to make a usable array or list of strings and integers I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Does np stand for Numerical Python? Is there any specific reason you want to use NumPy to do the task of splitting CSV file into multiple files? It can also be done using the standard python libraries.

Comment: im guessing here that he is doing vectorized computations on the data ... but thats just a guess ...

Comment: can you clarify `Now, instead of having 9 columns of values, where the last is a string, I now have the whole row grouped into one column.` ... that looks like a row in the output example ... I dont understand what you mean by the whole row grouped into one column... you mean tuple(or list?)?

Comment: I guess I should explain more thoroughly. I'm not that experienced in using python, I usually work within a limited range of functions. So I don't really understand the big picture of how to use arrays versus lists or tuples. I think the output is a tuple. I can't access, for example, any single item in the row.

Comment: yes, np is for numpy. I'm not just splitting the file up I'm using doing operations with the values, and there are some gaps in it, so that's why I am using np.genfromtxt()